# Fixed Floating Elements jQuery Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have added this code to my site (without all the stuff to set up the comments and headers): http://jsfiddle.net/WzLG2/3/ Below is the javascript.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var top = jQuery('#smi').offset().top - parseFloat(jQuery('#smi').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
// what the y position of the scroll is
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
// whether that's below the form
if (y >= top) {
// if so, ad the fixed class
jQuery('#smi').addClass('fixed');
} else {
// otherwise remove it
jQuery('#smi').removeClass('fixed');
}
});
});
```

My site: http://hollyshelpings.com

I'm trying to get the brown box underneath my header to scroll to the top and then stop there like in the jsfiddle.  I'm using thesis and I have jquery enabled.  I have wordpress and I already looked up how to use jquery in wordpress with replacing $ with jQuery.

I got the basis for the code from this site: Jquery for designers (it won't let me post the link)

I tested and jquery appears to be loading, I used firebug and I'm not seeing errors that pertain to this code (it looks like some plugins may have errors, however). I'm pretty new at coding so I'm not sure what else to test or how to troubleshoot much past this. My end goal is to use this for my social media icons instead of the tabs on the side.  Any guidance or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: After some further tests, it looks like the error is in how the height of the scroll bar is recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to check your javascript console and remove any errors you see coming up there, as they can cause problems elsewhere. Not saying it's related, but your call to jQuery('#commentluv') is broken.  I also notice you're using jQuery 1.4.2 which is really old, and should consider upgrading (maybe not to version 2 as that changed a lot, but at least to 1.9, maybe 1.10).

Comment: Ah.  I inactivated the plugin CommentLuv and it started working.  Now to play with it and see if I can get both to work.  Thanks.  That was an easier fix than I expected. :)